# Unitary transformation with eigenvectors of fourier basis

Tags: group-theory, fourier-analysis, quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to understand this statement made in https://users.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/randlectures/UVnotes/lec18.pdf in the last paragraph:

"Since U is multiplication by a group element, the eigenvectors of U should be elements of the fourier basis..."

What group element? Why should we expect the eigenvectors to be the fourier basis?